# .gitignore in xcode not taking effect

Tags: git, github, version-control, gitignore

My GitHub project has this structure:

- `folderA`: unrelated stuff
- `folderB` -> `MyProject` -> all Xcode related files including the `.xcodeproj`

In MyProject I've downloaded this `.gitignore`: https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Swift.gitignore

This `.gitgnore` has a line that says `xcuserdata`.
However when seeing the pending changes in git, I clearly still see files inside `MyProject.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/`.

My GitHub repository was empty, so I did not add any file before trying to add the gitgnore.

Answer (score 0):

To ignore all directories with that name you must add the following to .gitignore:

`xuserdata/`

With a trailing `/` that is. From the Git manual:

> If the pattern ends with a slash, it is removed for the purpose of the following description, but it would only find a match with a directory. In other words, **foo/ will match a directory foo and paths underneath it**, but will not match a regular file or a symbolic link foo (this is consistent with the way how pathspec works in general in Git).

If you add a line with `xuserdata` it will only ignore a file/directory named so on a path relative to the `.gitignore` so it won't find that directory you mentioned:

> If the pattern does not contain a slash /, Git treats it as a shell glob pattern and checks for a match against the pathname relative to the location of the .gitignore file (relative to the toplevel of the work tree if not from a .gitignore file).

Please let me know if this helped.